# package com.google.auth.http does not exist

Tags: java, gradle, google-api

So i keep running into these errors when trying to run a sample of a google api project:

```
dungbui@cloudshell:~ (tiw-leader-project-355316)$ gradle run

> Task :compileJava
/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java:8: error: package com.google.auth.http does not exist
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
                           ^
/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java:9: error: package com.google.auth.oauth2 does not exist
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
                             ^
/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
        ^
  symbol:   class GoogleCredentials
  location: class Create
/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable GoogleCredentials
  location: class Create
/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class HttpCredentialsAdapter
  location: class Create
5 errors

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

[image: build.gradle]

And here is my Create.java

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Spreadsheet;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.SpreadsheetProperties;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

/* Class to demonstrate the use of Spreadsheet Create API */
public class Create {
    /**
     * Create a new spreadsheet.
     *
     * @param title - the name of the sheet to be created.
     * @return newly created spreadsheet id
     * @throws IOException - if credentials file not found.
     */
    public static String createSpreadsheet(String title) throws IOException {
        /* Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
           TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
            guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application. */
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS));
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
                credentials);

        // Create the sheets API client
        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName("Sheets samples")
                .build();

        // Create new spreadsheet with a title
        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet()
                .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                        .setTitle(title));
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet)
                .setFields("spreadsheetId")
                .execute();
        // Prints the new spreadsheet id
        System.out.println("Spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId());
        return spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId();
    }
}
```

The Create java i take from the tutorial https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create

This is my first time trying having a go at google api, can somebody tell me how to fix this.

Comment: your problem is located in your `Creator` class, so maybe you could share it ?  `/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java:27: error:`

Comment: right my bad. Here it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the needed Dependency

try adding
`implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.1.0'`  to your build.gradle

The error refers to line 27 at `/home/dungbui/src/main/java/Create.java` which is declaring `GoogleCredentials`.